# TPM support does not work on Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, tpm

I have this issue with latest fedora 35 beta.

Clevis encrypt does not work, although I can find the TPM being active in the logs. Tried the enable operation from bios with no luck.

Please, see details here:

dmesg | grep -i tpm

```
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0x45bfe000 ACPI 2.0=0x45bfe014 TPMFinalLog=0x45ac5000 SMBIOS=0x439e3000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x439e1000 MEMATTR=0x3f8dc018 ESRT=0x3f8ea298 MOKvar=0x3f8df000 RNG=0x439e4b18 TPMEventLog=0x39f43018 
[    0.008084] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000045BE1000 00077B (v02 INSYDE Tpm2Tabl 00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.008086] ACPI: TPM2 0x0000000045BE0000 00004C (v04 INSYDE TGL-ULT  00000002 ACPI 00040000)
[    0.008128] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0x45be0000-0x45be004b]
[    1.192488] tpm_tis NTC0702:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0xFC, rev-id 1)
```

sudo echo hi | clevis encrypt tpm2 '{}' > my.jwe

```
Place your finger on the fingerprint reader
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tcti-device.c:442:Tss2_Tcti_Device_Init() Failed to open specified TCTI device file /dev/tpmrm0: Permission denied 
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr-dl.c:154:tcti_from_file() Could not initialize TCTI file: device 
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr.c:428:Tss2_TctiLdr_Initialize_Ex() Failed to instantiate TCTI 
Error executing command: TPM error: response code not recognized
```

EDIT: Opened a bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2018978

Comment: Hi Boris. You'd rather file a bug on bugzilla. That'd be more of an appropriate place.

Comment: Humm, AFAIK TrouSerS only supports TPM1

Comment: Yes, I got that, it seems I don't need this service I will remove this part from my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with latest Fedora 35 Update from 04.11.2021